# Can't get Audio to play

Tags: javascript, html

So I am new to coding and I am just trying to make a small project for myself. All it is a button that when you press it, it plays randomly one of three sounds. Something is going wrong though and I can't figure out what, anyone know?

cheers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Code\Experiments\HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT\Random Sound\Code\Random Sounds.css">


<h1> Random Sounds </h1>

<button id="press"> Press me! </button>


<script>
var num = 0

function pressed() {
  num = Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random())
  if (num == 1) {
    var audio1 = new Audio('C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Code\Experiments\HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT\Random Sound\Sounds\OFFICIAL Somewhere over the Rainbow
    - Israel IZ Kamakawiwoʻole.mp3');
    audio1.play()
  } else if (num == 2) {
    var audio2 = new Audio('C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Code\Experiments\HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT\Random Sound\Sounds\OFFICIAL Somewhere over the Rainbow
    - Israel IZ Kamakawiwoʻole.mp3');
    audio2.play()
  } else {
    var audio3 = new Audio('C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Code\Experiments\HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT\Random Sound\Sounds\OFFICIAL Somewhere over the Rainbow
    - Israel IZ Kamakawiwoʻole.mp3');
    audio3.play()
  }
}
press.onclick = pressed


</script>
```

A

Comment: Resource must be accessed via URL, not as path on your local computer.

Comment: `file://C:/Users/Owner` etc may work though - note the `file://` and the \ become `/`

Comment: So would the resource then look like this?

var audio3 = new Audio(URL('C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Code\Experiments\HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT\Random Sound\Sounds\OFFICIAL Somewhere over the Rainbow - Israel IZ Kamakawiwoʻole.mp3'))

Comment: Just put a relative path to the file (e.g `new Audio("Sounds/<filename>")`). Also, javascript won't let you load local files (due to CORS policy, look it up), unless you run a local web server (like XAMPP) on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!!

*Actually problem is your Audio Source path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/Owner/Google Drive/Code/Experiments/HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT/Random Sound/Code/Random Sounds.css">


<h1> Random Sounds </h1>

<button id="press"> Press me! </button>


<script>
var num = 0

function pressed() {
  num = Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random())
  if (num == 1) {
    var audio1 = new Audio('///C:/Users/Owner/Google Drive/Code/Experiments/HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT/Random Sound/Sounds/OFFICIAL Somewhere over the Rainbow
    - Israel IZ Kamakawiwoʻole.mp3');
    audio1.play()
  } else if (num == 2) {
    var audio2 = new Audio('///C:/Users/Owner/Google Drive/Code/Experiments/HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT/Random Sound/Sounds/OFFICIAL Somewhere over the Rainbow
    - Israel IZ Kamakawiwoʻole.mp3');
    audio2.play()
  } else {
    var audio3 = new Audio('///C:/Users/Owner/Google Drive/Code/Experiments/HTML-CSS-JAVASCRIPT/Random Sound/Sounds/OFFICIAL Somewhere over the Rainbow
    - Israel IZ Kamakawiwoʻole.mp3');
    audio3.play()
  }
}
press.onclick = pressed


</script>
```